# Why does a bucket full of muddy water does not show its surface but a mug of water does

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Think I have certain amount of muddy water in a bucket. I pour the same water into a mug. In case of mug I can see its lower surface (surface underneath water) but in case of bucket. Anyway both cases mud density should be same. Then why does it occur?

Answer (score 1):

The reason muddy water restricts visibility in the first place is because light scatters off of the mud particles in the water. Deeper water means that light coming from the bottom of the bucket/mug must pass through more muddy water before hitting your eye, so more of it is scattered, leading to lower visibility.